# Typescript function return promise

Tags: typescript

I'm having a hard time understanding how to set the return type on a function.

The issue is that this function (api call) could return an array of objects `[{}, {}, {}]`

or and object with some properties, and than the array.

```
{
  "count": 311,
  "next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/....",
  "previous": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/...",
  "results": [{}, {}, {}]
}
```

What I have is the specific API-call function

```
async function fetchStuff(): Promise<IApiResponse<IStuff[]>> {
    return get({ baseProperty: 'stuff' })
}
```

Which calls the general "get" method that I created

```
async function get(baseProperty: string): Promise<IApiResponse<any>> {
    try {
        const { data } = await Vue.$axios.get(baseProperty)
        return data
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        throw err
    }
}
```

The interface I created is this

```
export interface IApiResponse<T> {
    count: number
    next: string
    previous: string
    results: T
}
```

The problem, as I said is that not all the api calls will return the same thing, how can I allow for different return types in my `get` method?

Comment: I think Typescript has you covered with "union types". Declare `type ActualApiResponse<T> = IApiResponse<T> | T` and return that instead? Using `ActualApiResponse<T>` as return type means return type can be either `IApiResponse<T>` ***or*** `T`

Comment: That did it, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. I posted an answer now we got to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript has you covered with [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types).

You might choose to declare a new union type

```
type ActualApiResponse<T> = IApiResponse<T> | T
```

and use it as follows:

```
async function fetchStuff(): Promise<ActualApiResponse<IStuff[]>> {
    // ...
}
```

or simply take the more direct approach of:

```
async function fetchStuff(): Promise<IApiResponse<IStuff[]> | IStuff[]> {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change your "get" method signature to:

```
async function get<T>(baseProperty: string): Promise<IApiResponse<T>>
```

Comment: That still doesn't solve my issue because that get is still returning the `Promise<IApiResponse>` which is not true, becuse it could just be a `Promise<any>` or `Promise<T>` in this case